# Android Retrofit : Wait for response

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2, android-webservice

I am implementing retrofit 2 in my app to call web services. My code is as below :

**SignUp.java**

```
ConnectionDetector connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(SignUpActivity.this);
if (connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListCountryDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    GetCountryList getCountryList = new GetCountryList();
    arrayListCountryDetails = getCountryList.CallWebServiceForCountryDetails(this);

    // The app should wait here till the above retrofit web service calling returns response


    CountryDetailsAdapter countryDetailsAdapter = new CountryDetailsAdapter(SignUpActivity.this, arrayListCountryDetails);
    spinnerCountryName.setAdapter(countryDetailsAdapter);
} else {
    String message = "No internet connection.";
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**GetCountryList.java**

```
public class GetCountryList {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    APIService mAPIService;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListCountryDetails;

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> CallWebServiceForCountryDetails(final Context context) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        arrayListCountryDetails = new ArrayList<>();

        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
        mAPIService.getCountryDetails().enqueue(new Callback<CountryDetailsResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CountryDetailsResponseModel> call, Response<CountryDetailsResponseModel> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    HashMap<String, String> cntDetails = new HashMap<>();
                    cntDetails.put("airLineID", "0");
                    cntDetails.put("airLineName", "Select Airline");
                    arrayListCountryDetails.add(cntDetails);

                    // Get response
                    try {
                        if (response.body().getStatus() == 200 && response.body().getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                            for (int count = 0; count < response.body().getCountry().size(); count++) {
                                cntDetails = new HashMap<>();
                                String countryID = response.body().getCountry().get(count).getCountryId();
                                String countryName = response.body().getCountry().get(count).getCountryName();

                                cntDetails.put("countryID", countryID);
                                cntDetails.put("countryName", countryName);
                                arrayListCountryDetails.add(cntDetails);
                            }

                            // do UI work here
                            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        } else {
                            // do UI work here
                            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // do UI work here
                        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AirLineDetailsResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                // do UI work here
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        return arrayListCountryDetails;
    }
}
```

When i am executing the code i am getting null pointer exception error as :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.abc.xyz.SignUpActivity.initializeScreen(SignUpActivity.java:176)
    at com.abc.xyz.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:147)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

**I know that this is because the spinner initialization execution is takes place before retrofit response.**

Please suggest me how can i wait for the retrofit response. What changes i need to do in above code. Please i am not able to move ahead due to this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: short and simple use AsyncTask and set your adapter after you have country list in **arrayListCountryDetails** check your list size >0 before set adapter

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly do something like the following. I just placed the necessary part of code inside the `AsyncTask` methods. Modify as necessary.

```
if (connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {


        // The app should wait here till the above retrofit web service calling returns response

    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Map<String, String>>>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            List<Map<String, String>> arrayListCountryDetails = new ArrayList<>();
            GetCountryList getCountryList = new GetCountryList();
            arrayListCountryDetails = getCountryList.CallWebServiceForCountryDetails(this);
            return arrayListCountryDetails;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, String>> arrayListCountryDetails) {
            CountryDetailsAdapter countryDetailsAdapter = new CountryDetailsAdapter(SignUpActivity.this, arrayListCountryDetails);
            spinnerCountryName.setAdapter(countryDetailsAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
    task.execute();

}
```

Also remove any UI calls from your `GetCountryList` since this will be run on "background"

Comment: `AsyncTask` is the right way to do when accessing databases, urls, and other "background" processes in order not to block the UI. Do some research to come to your own conclusions https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @pleft retrofit network call already in background ,I don't think its good way to use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Spinner object while loading data and set adapter after load complete

```
public class GetCountryList {
ProgressDialog dialog;
APIService mAPIService;


public void  CallWebServiceForCountryDetails(final Context context,final Spinner spinnerCountryName) {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

   final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListCountryDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
    mAPIService.getCountryDetails().enqueue(new Callback<CountryDetailsResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CountryDetailsResponseModel> call, Response<CountryDetailsResponseModel> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                HashMap<String, String> cntDetails = new HashMap<>();
                cntDetails.put("airLineID", "0");
                cntDetails.put("airLineName", "Select Airline");
                arrayListCountryDetails.add(cntDetails);

                // Get response
                try {
                    if (response.body().getStatus() == 200 && response.body().getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                        for (int count = 0; count < response.body().getCountry().size(); count++) {
                            cntDetails = new HashMap<>();
                            String countryID = response.body().getCountry().get(count).getCountryId();
                            String countryName = response.body().getCountry().get(count).getCountryName();

                            cntDetails.put("countryID", countryID);
                            cntDetails.put("countryName", countryName);
                            arrayListCountryDetails.add(cntDetails);
                        }

                        // do UI work here
                        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                  //set Adapter 

                  CountryDetailsAdapter countryDetailsAdapter = new CountryDetailsAdapter(context, arrayListCountryDetails);
                  spinnerCountryName.setAdapter(countryDetailsAdapter);
                    } else {
                        // do UI work here
                        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // do UI work here
                    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AirLineDetailsResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            // do UI work here
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });


}
```